# How to configure trigger's expiration date

Tags: java, spring-boot, quartz-scheduler

I have next JobSchedulerService:

```
@Slf4j
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class QuartzServiceImpl implements JobSchedulerService {

    private final SchedulerFactoryBean schedulerFactoryBean;

    @Override
    public void scheduleJob(LocalDateTime date, Class jobClass, boolean repeatUntilManuallyStopped, Map<String, Object> jobDataMap) {
        String expirationDate = date.toString();
        String name = jobClass.getName() + "_";;
        JobDetail jobDetail = JobBuilder.newJob(jobClass).withIdentity(name + expirationDate)
                .storeDurably().build();

        if(jobDataMap != null){
            jobDetail.getJobDataMap().putAll(jobDataMap);
        }
        jobDetail.getJobDataMap().put("expirationDate", expirationDate);

        ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = date.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault());
        SimpleTrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.newTrigger().withIdentity(name + expirationDate)
                .startAt(Date.from(zonedDateTime.toInstant()))
                .endAt(Date.from(zonedDateTime.plusMinutes(2).toInstant()))
                .withSchedule(repeatUntilManuallyStopped ?
                        SimpleScheduleBuilder.repeatMinutelyForever().withMisfireHandlingInstructionFireNow() : SimpleScheduleBuilder.simpleSchedule().withMisfireHandlingInstructionFireNow())
                .build();
        
        schedule(jobDetail, trigger, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void scheduleJob(LocalDateTime date, int intervalInMinutes, int count, Class jobClass,  Map<String, Object> jobDataMap) {
        String expirationDate = date.toString();
        String name = jobClass.getName() + "_";
        JobDetail jobDetail = JobBuilder.newJob(jobClass).withIdentity(name + expirationDate)
                .storeDurably().build();

        jobDetail.getJobDataMap().putAll(jobDataMap);
        jobDetail.getJobDataMap().put("expirationDate", expirationDate);

        LocalDateTime currentTime = LocalDateTime.now();
        LocalDateTime startDateTime = date;

        int decrement = count;

        while (decrement != 0) {
            startDateTime = startDateTime.minusMinutes(intervalInMinutes);
            decrement --;
            if(currentTime.compareTo(startDateTime) >= 0) {
                startDateTime = currentTime;
                break;
            }
        }

        SimpleTrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.newTrigger().withIdentity(name + expirationDate)
                .startAt(Date.from(startDateTime.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant()))
                .withSchedule(SimpleScheduleBuilder.repeatMinutelyForTotalCount(count - decrement, intervalInMinutes)
                        .withMisfireHandlingInstructionFireNow())
                .build();

        schedule(jobDetail, trigger, false);
    }

    public Date schedule(JobDetail jobDetail, SimpleTrigger trigger, boolean isUnique) {
        Scheduler scheduler = schedulerFactoryBean.getScheduler();

        try {
            boolean alreadyExists = scheduler.checkExists(jobDetail.getKey());

            if(isUnique && alreadyExists) {
                throw new ApiException(ApiError.RESOURCE_EXISTS);
            } else if(!alreadyExists){
                Date date = scheduler.scheduleJob(jobDetail, trigger);
                scheduler.start();
                return date;
            } else {
                return trigger.getStartTime();
            }
        } catch (ObjectAlreadyExistsException e) {
            if(isUnique) {
                ExceptionTracker.captureException(e);
                log.error("Could not schedule job with key {} and description {}. Job already exists", jobDetail.getKey().getName(), jobDetail.getDescription());
                throw new ApiException(ApiError.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
            } else {
                return trigger.getStartTime();
            }
        } catch (Exception e){
            ExceptionTracker.captureException(e);
            log.error("Could not schedule job with key {} and description {}. Localized message => {}", jobDetail.getKey().getName(), jobDetail.getDescription(), e.getLocalizedMessage());
            throw new ApiException(ApiError.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        }
    }
}
```

Here I am setting time for expiration after 2 minutes

> .endAt(Date.from(zonedDateTime.plusMinutes(2).toInstant()))

And I shutdown the application right after it creates job and trigger. But when I startup again it runs expired trigger, even if the time has passed in table *qrtz_triggers.end_time*.

My properties file for Quartz:

```
org.quartz.scheduler.instanceName=PostcreditService
org.quartz.scheduler.instanceId=AUTO
org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount=5
org.quartz.jobStore.class=org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX
org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass=org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.PostgreSQLDelegate
org.quartz.jobStore.useProperties=true
org.quartz.jobStore.misfireThreshold=60000
org.quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix=postcredit.qrtz_
org.quartz.jobStore.isClustered=true
org.quartz.plugin.shutdownHook.class=org.quartz.plugins.management.ShutdownHookPlugin
org.quartz.plugin.shutdownHook.cleanShutdown=TRUE
```

Configs:

```
@Configuration
public class QuartzConfig {

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Bean
    public JobFactory jobFactory() {
        AutowiringSpringBeanJobFactory jobFactory = new AutowiringSpringBeanJobFactory();
        jobFactory.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
        return jobFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public SchedulerFactoryBean schedulerFactoryBean() throws IOException {

        SchedulerFactoryBean schedulerFactory = new SchedulerFactoryBean();
        schedulerFactory.setQuartzProperties(quartzProperties());
        schedulerFactory.setWaitForJobsToCompleteOnShutdown(true);
        schedulerFactory.setAutoStartup(true);
        schedulerFactory.setJobFactory(jobFactory());
        schedulerFactory.setDataSource(dataSource);
        return schedulerFactory;
    }

    public Properties quartzProperties() throws IOException {
        PropertiesFactoryBean propertiesFactoryBean = new PropertiesFactoryBean();
        propertiesFactoryBean.setLocation(new ClassPathResource("/quartz.properties"));
        propertiesFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet();
        return propertiesFactoryBean.getObject();
    }

}
```

Please, help!

Answer (score 1):

You are setting trigger's expire time correctly using `TriggerBuilder.endAt()`

> And I shutdown the application right after it creates job and trigger.
> But when I startup again it runs expired trigger, even if the time has
> passed in table qrtz_triggers.end_time.

This happens because on restart quartz checks for misfired triggers and try to rerun those based on the configured mirefire instruction which in your case is `withMisfireHandlingInstructionFireNow`. Now the thing is that this particluar instruction does not consider the trigger's endAt() time and always set a new `nextFireTime` and rerun it.

For your case, there are other misfire instructions that you may want to consider like `withMisfireHandlingInstructionNowWithExistingCount`